# Setting document mode in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

I have this old web site that runs fine in IE8, but stops working in IE10.  I tested this by setting the document mode in the Developer tools (F12) to "standard settings for IE8" (ALT-8).

To set the document mode in IE with HTML I have added a meta tag in my page; it now starts with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
...
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

If I now go back to the page it doesn't work.  The browser DOES see the meta tag tho: in the developer tools the option "Standard setting for IE8" (ALT-8) now has an added "(Standard settings for this page).  If I chose this option the page works fine.  Problem though is that when I use the first option  - "standard settings" (ALT-S) the page does not work.  Even though these standard settings should be the IE8 standard settings.  What is going wrong?

Comment: I have tested it some more, and if I set the page to "standard settings (ALT-S)" and then reload, it stay on "standard settings".  If I come from a different page tho and it's on "standard settings" the meta tag causes the browser to go to "standard settings for IE8".  I guess this means my problem is solved.  Not sure why it won't change the settings on a page reload tho.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this but it might work. You can edit

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

by the line given below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Here, `**IE=edge**` means it will directly open it in standard mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there was never a problem in the first place.  In testing - reloading the page - it went wrong, but people come from a different page, and then it works fine.